# 'react-native' not importing correctly to page

Tags: javascript, react-native

As you can see in the photo, there are 3 dots under react-native. On other projects when I hover over it it says as follows:

module "/Users/mac/Library/Caches/typescript/4.5/node_modules/@types/react-native/index"

But when I hover over in this new project, it says as follows:

module "/Users/mac/Desktop/project/rn-zoom/node_modules/react-native/index"

I guess that's why when I type "Button", the automatic import option does not appear, or when I start typing props, the automatic import option does not appear. What causes this situation and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install Plugins:

React Native Tools &  ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets

Now check that at your bottom right corner the selected language is React.

Answer (score 0):

delete your node-module folder and run `npm install` it will work for you. and also run the command of clear cache.